# SQL-server syntax error when combining queries (pass-through query)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, pass-through

I'm trying to combine 2 queries to a sql-server pass-through query (PTQ). Both queries, when coded separately in Access, work. When combining these Access codes to one query, it still works in Access.
But when I format the field names to T-sql, and try to run as a PTQ, I get a syntax error near "GROUP". When I delete this "GROUP BY" line, I get a syntax error near ";".

```
SELECT jaar, 
       maand, 
       wicode, 
       pg_intern_code, 
       pg_kriss_code, 
       pg_kriss_naam, 
       Count(pc0517.dbo.resul.klavnr) AS AantalVanKLAVNR 
FROM   (SELECT Year(pc0517.dbo.resul.created)  AS JAAR, 
               Month(pc0517.dbo.resul.created) AS MAAND, 
               pc0517.dbo.resul.wicode, 
               dbo.tblproductgroep_intern.pg_intern_code, 
               dbo.tblproductgroep_kriss.pg_kriss_code, 
               dbo.tblproductgroep_kriss.pg_kriss_naam, 
               pc0517.dbo.resul.klavnr 
        FROM   (dbo.tblproductgroep_kriss 
                INNER JOIN (dbo.tblproductgroep_intern 
                            INNER JOIN dbo.tblrobbe_pg 
                                    ON dbo.tblproductgroep_intern.pg_intern_id = 
                                       dbo.tblrobbe_pg.pg_code_intern_id) 
                        ON dbo.tblproductgroep_kriss.pg_kriss_id = 
                           dbo.tblrobbe_pg.pg_code_kriss_id) 
               INNER JOIN pc0517.dbo.resul 
                       ON dbo.tblrobbe_pg.robbe_pg_naam = 
                          pc0517.dbo.resul.prcode 
        WHERE  ( ( Year(pc0517.dbo.resul.created) = 2012 ) 
                 AND ( pc0517.dbo.resul.kanaal = "gg" ) )) 
GROUP  BY jaar, 
          maand, 
          wicode, 
          pg_intern_code, 
          pg_kriss_code, 
          pg_kriss_naam;
```

Other PTQ's on the same database (even combined with the PC0517 database), work without any glitch, but I'm totally new to SQL-server, so I don't know all the conventions yet, and am probably overlooking something basic...

TIA

Comment: TSQL doesn't like double quotes.  Change "gg" to 'gg'.

Comment: Ugh, Access makes some nasty stuff.

Comment: Thanks to whoever changed the formatting :) And the nasty stuff might also be due to the fact that I have to combine an awful lot of tables (not my database)...

Answer (score 2):

I corrected a variety of things: (1) put the joins in the right order (2) removed misplaced parentheses (3) 
 added table aliases for readability (4) removed double quotes around `"gg"` (5) made the query against r.created an open-ended range so that an index could be used if it exists. I also removed `jaar` from the inner query in the grouping - based on the where clause, this can never be anything other than `2012`.

I don't know what Access will do with this if you paste it back into there, but you should be able to confirm this is a more correct query than the garbage Access produced for you by running it against SQL Server directly. If Access still breaks this, I would put it in a stored procedure or a view in SQL Server, and point Access at that.

```
SELECT 
   jaar = 2012, 
   maand, 
   wicode, 
   pg_intern_code, 
   pg_kriss_code, 
   pg_kriss_naam, 
   COUNT(klavnr) AS AantalVanKLAVNR 
FROM   
(
    SELECT 
       maand = MONTH(r.created), 
       r.wicode, 
       i.pg_intern_code, 
       k.pg_kriss_code, 
       k.pg_kriss_naam, 
       r.klavnr 
    FROM 
       dbo.tblproductgroep_kriss AS k
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblrobbe_pg AS tr 
       ON k.pg_kriss_id = tr.pg_code_kriss_id
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblproductgroep_intern AS i 
       ON i.pg_intern_id = tr.pg_code_intern_id
    INNER JOIN pc0517.dbo.resul AS r 
       ON tr.robbe_pg_naam = r.prcode 
    WHERE 
       r.created >= '20120101' AND r.created < '20130101'
       AND r.kanaal = 'gg'
) AS x 
GROUP BY 
   maand, 
   wicode, 
   pg_intern_code, 
   pg_kriss_code, 
   pg_kriss_naam;
```

It can also be simplified as:

```
    SELECT 
       jaar = 2012,
       maand = MONTH(r.created), 
       r.wicode, 
       i.pg_intern_code, 
       k.pg_kriss_code, 
       k.pg_kriss_naam, 
       r.klavnr 
    FROM 
       dbo.tblproductgroep_kriss AS k
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblrobbe_pg AS tr 
       ON k.pg_kriss_id = tr.pg_code_kriss_id
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblproductgroep_intern AS i 
       ON i.pg_intern_id = tr.pg_code_intern_id
    INNER JOIN pc0517.dbo.resul AS r 
       ON tr.robbe_pg_naam = r.prcode 
    WHERE 
       r.created >= '20120101' AND r.created < '20130101'
       AND r.kanaal = 'gg'
    GROUP BY 
       MONTH(r.created), 
       r.wicode, 
       i.pg_intern_code, 
       k.pg_kriss_code, 
       k.pg_kriss_naam;
```

(In other words, the subquery seems unnecessary.)

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you so much for taking the time!